# How to scan SQL array to []int64 in Go?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, psql

I am scanning an array of int from Postgres DB and it is returning as `[]uint8`. I need them in `[]int64`, how can I convert them into `[]int64` or how can I return them from the DB as `[]int64`? In my query I am selecting using the Array function in Postgres: `Array(col1)` where col1 is serial.

The error I am getting is:

```
unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type []int64
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using `github.com/lib/pq`, just use [`Int64Array`](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Int64Array).

```
col1arr := []int64{}
arr := pq.Int64Array{}
err := rows.Scan(&arr)
// ...
col1arr = []int64(arr)
```

Comment: can then I parse from pg.Int64Array to int64?

Comment: thank you that is what I needed, but I am getting an error: undefined: pq.Int64Array. I imported the library

Comment: How did you import the library? If `import _ "github.com/lib/pq"` then remove the `_`. If that doesn't help, update it with `go get -u github.com/lib/pq`.

Comment: thanks I needed to update the library as you specified